# npm package error,<--- JS stacktrace ---> FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: reactjs, npm

#running other reactjs projects work but running some others run into this error, increasing memory is not solving the issue and clearing cache is also not healing the node,I am stack#

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Starting the development server...


<--- Last few GCs --->

[24628:0000025F59DB78F0]    10935 ms: Scavenge 318.7 (375.5) -> 318.7 (375.5) MB, 37.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.990, current mu = 0.984) allocation failure 
[24628:0000025F59DB78F0]    13187 ms: Scavenge 510.7 (567.5) -> 510.7 (567.5) MB, 165.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.990, current mu = 0.984) allocation failure 
[24628:0000025F59DB78F0]    18581 ms: Scavenge 894.7 (951.6) -> 894.7 (951.6) MB, 315.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.990, current mu = 0.984) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF635DA7B7F v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+114079
 2: 00007FF635D34546 DSA_meth_get_flags+65542
 3: 00007FF635D353FD node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF63666B29E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF63665587D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF6364F8C4C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1468
 7: 00007FF635FC8D89 v8::internal::Isolate::FatalProcessOutOfHeapMemory+25
 8: 00007FF63632D115 v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary,v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity<v8::internal::Isolate>+341
 9: 00007FF63632AE66 v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::NumberDictionary,v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::Add<v8::internal::Isolate>+86
10: 00007FF6363C8595 v8::internal::FeedbackNexus::ic_state+32581
11: 00007FF6363C29F2 v8::internal::FeedbackNexus::ic_state+9122
12: 00007FF636375714 v8::internal::JSObject::AddDataElement+1092
13: 00007FF63633442B v8::internal::StringSet::Add+1835
14: 00007FF63637700C v8::internal::JSObject::DefineAccessor+1644
15: 00007FF6363764AB v8::internal::JSObject::AddProperty+3083
16: 00007FF63637667B v8::internal::JSObject::AddProperty+3547
17: 00007FF636240658 v8::internal::Runtime::GetObjectProperty+5064
18: 00007FF6366F8F91 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
19: 00007FF636722E5D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+666141
20: 00007FF63670CD2A v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+575722
21: 00007FF63668B53E v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+45310
22: 0000025F5C052EC8
```

Comment: What command are you running ? 
What is your version of nodejs ?

Comment: npm start is the command i am running to start the development env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a **corrupted** installation of **nodejs**.

Uninstall and reinstall your nodejs.

Clean your node_modules and reinstall all your dependencies.

Run again and tell us if that solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case when i try to execute a npm test on angular, i had the same error. The solution was:

1. reinstall node_modules on your project
2. npm install

This solve my problem